# Unexpected queries are being executed after connecting to MySQL while using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

```
public User getUserOnlyByUserName(String username) {

    LOGGER.info(" into getUserByIdJOIN ServiceImpl in UserDao------>>>>>>");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(USERNAME, username));
    Object obj =  criteria.uniqueResult();

    if(obj==null){
        return null;
    }
        session.close();
LOGGER.info(" out of getUserByIdJOIN ServiceImpl in UserDao------>>>>>>");
        return (User) obj;

}
```

197 Connect root@localhost on (dbname)

The mysql log for the same is shown below

> 197 Connect  root@localhost on itaf4  197 Query  /*
>   mysql-connector-java-5.1.42 ( Revision:
>   1f61b0b0270d9844b006572ba4e77f19c0f230d4 ) */***SELECT 
>   @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment,
>   @@character_set_client AS character_set_client,
>   @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection,
>   @@character_set_results AS character_set_results,
>   @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@init_connect AS
>   init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license
>   AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names,
>   @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_buffer_length AS
>   net_buffer_length, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout,
>   @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size, @@query_cache_type AS
>   query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS
>   system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@tx_isolation AS
>   tx_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
>      197 Query  SET NAMES latin1
>      197 Query  SET character_set_results = NULL
>      197 Query  SET autocommit=1
>      197 Query  SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
>
> 197 Query  select this_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, this_.accountNonExpired as accountN2_3_0_, this_.accountNonLocked as
>   accountN3_3_0_, this_.attempts as attempts4_3_0_,
>   this_.credentialsNonExpired as credenti5_3_0_, this_.enabled as
>   enabled6_3_0_, this_.firstname as firstnam7_3_0_, this_.lastAttempt as
>   lastAtte8_3_0_, this_.lastname as lastname9_3_0_, this_.password as
>   passwor10_3_0_, this_.roleId as roleId12_3_0_, this_.username as
>   usernam11_3_0_ from users this_ where this_.username='demo_admin'
>           197 Query SHOW WARNINGS
>           197 Quit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those SQL statements are not executed by Hibernate. The MySQL Driver execute them for you.

If you want to know what statements Hibernate generates, then you should configure an SQL query logger, like [`datasource-proxy`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/). This way, you are going to know for sure what JDBC  statements were generated explicitly by the application.

In your case, all those statements are executed when the database connection is initialized. You can debug the MySQL Connector/J driver and see for yourself.

If you see those logs many times, it means you don't reuse connections, which is bad for performance and system scalability. After configuring a connection pooling solution, make sure you use [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) as well so that you know what happens underneath.

Comment: Thanks that worked great and configured HikariCP as well. Its fine now